# Include the current year and month to the base url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add the **current year and month** to this url, after the index to call my event calender

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Event/index'); ?>">Events</a></li>
```

like this ---->  index.php/Event/index/year/month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP `date()` for this,

```
<?php
$suffix = date("Y/m");
?>

<li><a href="<?php echo base_url("index.php/Event/index/$suffix"); ?>">Events</a></li>
```

This will produce something similar to,

```
<li><a href="https://www.example.com/index.php/Event/index/2021/05">Events</a></li>
```

Read about PHP [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)